# Re-using SpecFlow test scripts in different solutions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ui-automation, specflow

We have different C# Visual Studio solutions in different Git repositories. Each repository contains source code that needs functional tests and these tests will be integrated with Azure DevOps. The idea is to have a single C# testing automation framework with generic steps, hooks and logic that can be used among all solutions.

Some ideas I came up with:

- Having a separate repository with automation framework files and just copy and paste hooks, steps, configurations files, etc. for each of the solutions / repositories.
- Create a SpecFlow project inside of each solution / repository and maintain one automation framework for each solution.
- Use NuGet to pack the testing framework and install it into each of the solutions. I personally like this last approach but I am not sure how it can be achieved.

Any suggestions or ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: We don't use Specflow, just C#/Selenium and MSTest inside Visual Studio.  We basically use the first bullet point method you have outlined above.  Not the best solution, but that's what we do.  It is more of a visual guide people can reference, and copy and paste pieces as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Bindings from External Assemblies](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Use-Bindings-from-External-Assemblies.html), which allows you to create a general class library containing your step definitions and hooks, and then reuse them in multiple test projects.

If using SpecFlow.json in your test project, add this:

```json
{
  ... other JSON settings for SpecFlow ...

  "stepAssemblies": [
    {
      "assembly": "NameOfYourSharedBindings"
    }
  ]
}
```

If using App.config:

```xml
<specFlow>
  <!-- other SpecFlow settings -->

  <stepAssemblies>
    <stepAssembly assembly="NameOfYourSharedBindings" />
  </stepAssemblies>
</specFlow>
```

Just replace `NameOfYourSharedBindings` with the file name of the DLL file containing your shared steps and hooks. Be sure to add a project reference to your test project so it references the class library project containing your shared steps.

You are not limited to step definitions in another project inside the same Visual Studio solution. You can reference pre-compiled DLL files as well as NuGet packages. So, really, options 2 or 3 would work for you. Just pick which one makes the most sense for your use case.